# Creating an extension point for websphere application server

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, websphere, application-server

I know that WAS supports the eclipse extension APIs, since we use several extension points to extend functionality of other applications. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to create my own extension point that others implement. I know that this is supported, because I found some documentation http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tweb_regfilter_extension.html.

I have created a plugin.xml and a schema file, and these are both in a jar that is loaded in a WAS shared library. I have also created a test implementation that is a web app.

However, the problem is, when I call Platform.createInstances("my.point.id", "class", true); to get the instance of the extension point that have been added, I don't get any created instances, and I don't know why.

Have I missed a step or something?

Comment: It would help to understand your issue, if you could add your `plugin.xml` which specifies your new extension point. Also, are there any messages in the log files of the application server?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is an old question that I have since figured out. The problem was that I didn't realise that the id of the plugin.xml is a prefix of the id when declaring an extension point. So, my test implementation didn't use the correct id, and wasn't picked up.